# Significantly slow down iOS app

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering

I want to see an animation in details of an iOS app (game), that is not done by me so I have no access to its source code. What would you advise to make the transitions drastically slower, so that to see all the moves and shapes changes in slow-motion?

May be there are apps that can do a kind of a screencast on the device itself then I can open it in a movie editor on a laptop?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to screen broadcast from iOS. But the question is off topic. I recommend searching google for this answer. :)

Comment: I realize you don't have access to the source code, but just for future reference: The iOS Simulator allows you to slow down animations from the Debug menu (CMD+T). Other than that, like you said, use something like Reflector (AirPlay recorder) and then open up the video in iMovie and slow it down.

Answer (score -1):

Press Cmd + T in the simulator to slow down animations.

Comment: This does not answer the question and was already posted as a comment anyway.